# Apex trigger to update fields on opportunity when another trigger updates the Owner of the opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

We have a trigger which keeps the account owner and opportunity owner in sync. So whenever an account owner is updated it automatically updates the opportunity owner to the same as account owner. 
I wanted to have a trigger on the opportunity which checks the opportunity owner and whenever it is changed to admin, the fields(Stage, Closed lost reason and close date should be updated).

```
Trigger updOpportunity on opportunity (after update) {
    list<id> oppIds=new list<id>();
    list<opportunity> oppLst=new list<opportunity>();
    map<string,AdminRecordTypeSetting__c> idsMap=AdminRecordTypeSetting__c.getAll();
    // to fetch ids from custom settings

    //retrieving all the Record Type Ids and admin ID
    String adminid=idsMap.get('Admin').AssociatedID__c;
    String AmfreeSub=idsMap.get('Acct_Mgmt_Free_Subscriber').AssociatedID__c;
    String AmPaySub=idsMap.get('Acct_Mgmt_Paying_Subscriber').AssociatedID__c;
    String FreeSub=idsMap.get('Free_Subscriber').AssociatedID__c;
    String PaySub=idsMap.get('Paying_Subscriber').AssociatedID__c;
    String PremFreeSub=idsMap.get('Premier_Free_Subscriber').AssociatedID__c;
    String PremPaySub=idsMap.get('Premier_Paying_Subscriber').AssociatedID__c;


    //user adminuser=[select id from user where Name='Admin'];

    for(opportunity o:trigger.new){
        if(o.ownerid!=trigger.oldmap.get(o.id).ownerid &&o.ownerid==adminid){
            oppIds.add(o.id);
        }
    }
    for(opportunity opp:[SELECT id,StageName,CloseDate,Closed_Lost_Reason__c,RecordTypeId from opportunity where id IN:oppIds]){
        if(opp.RecordTypeId==AmFreeSub||opp.RecordTypeId==AmPaySub||opp.RecordTypeId==FreeSub||opp.RecordTypeId==PaySub||opp.RecordTypeId==PremFreeSub||opp.RecordTypeId==PremPaySub) {
            opp.StageName='Closed Lost';
            opp.CloseDate=system.today();
            opp.Closed_Lost_Reason__c='Account Scrub';
            oppLst.add(opp);
        }
    }
    update oppLst;
}
```

I am currently having an after update trigger which fires only when the opportunity owner is updated manually. But i wanted to have an before update trigger which updates the fields when the other trigger updates the account owner.
Any help is greatly apreciated.
Thanks

Comment: "only when the opportunity owner is updated manually." - I am just curious, why do you think so?

Comment: I am also confused.  Is this the current trigger, or an attempt to do what you are describing?

Comment: "only when the opportunity owner is updated manually." - I am just curious, why do you think so?
Also - can you provide me with more information - why you want this before insert trigger? Is something wrong with after update? Also Why do you use Custom setting to keep profiles map - Isn't static map better Idea? Also can't your last loop be upgraded by moving requiments from If to query?

Comment: I am sorry about my confusion. When it is an after update it works. But the requirement is this needs to be dependent on the other trigger which updates the opportunity owner to the same as account owner whenever the account owner is changed. If i explicitly perform an update on the opportunity by changing the opportunity owner then this trigger fires. I am not sure why this wont fire when the other trigger updates the opp owner based on account owner.